# erlang otp application is not restarted when it crashes

Tags: erlang

I've been reading the book *[Erlang and OTP In Action](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Erlang-OTP-Action-Martin-Logan/dp/1933988789)* and trying the source code in chapter 4 which builds an OTP application.

There is a gen_server that has these call back methods ([full source](https://github.com/erlware/Erlang-and-OTP-in-Action-Source/blob/master/chapter_04/tcp_rpc/src/tr_server.erl)):

```erlang
%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_server callbacks
%%%===================================================================

init([Port]) ->
    {ok, LSock} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, true}]),
    {ok, #state{port = Port, lsock = LSock}, 0}.

handle_call(get_count, _From, State) ->
    {reply, {ok, State#state.request_count}, State}.

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State}.

handle_info({tcp, Socket, RawData}, State) ->
    do_rpc(Socket, RawData),
    RequestCount = State#state.request_count,
    {noreply, State#state{request_count = RequestCount + 1}};
handle_info(timeout, #state{lsock = LSock} = State) ->
    {ok, _Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(LSock),
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================
```

The superviser `init([])` method looks like this ([full source](https://github.com/erlware/Erlang-and-OTP-in-Action-Source/blob/master/chapter_04/tcp_rpc/src/tr_sup.erl)):

```erlang
init([]) ->
    Server = {tr_server, {tr_server, start_link, []},
              permanent, 2000, worker, [tr_server]},
    Children = [Server],
    RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 0, 1},
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

I've started the application with `application:start(tcp_rpc)` and telneted into the application.  When I exit the telnet session, the following erlang error was thrown:

```erlang
=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Mar-2015::08:12:58 ===
** Generic server tr_server terminating 
** Last message in was {tcp_closed,#Port<0.733>}
** When Server state == {state,1055,#Port<0.725>,5}
** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,[{tr_server,handle_info,
                                [{tcp_closed,#Port<0.733>},
                                 {state,1055,#Port<0.725>,5}],
                                [{file,"src/tr_server.erl"},{line,87}]},
                     {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,
                                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,593}]},
                     {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,659}]},
                     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                               [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}

=INFO REPORT==== 11-Mar-2015::08:12:58 ===
    application: tcp_rpc
    exited: shutdown
    type: temporary
```

I can see that the application is crashing because it doesn't have a handler for `tcp_closed`, however I was expecting the application to be restarted by the supervisor, but it wasn't.

Should the supervisor have restarted the application?

Comment: No, what you wrote meant that the supervisor is allowing 0 crashes, so after the first time the server crashes the supervisor gives, it has reached its count, which then the means that the application gives up.

Comment: I guess I just didn't take onboard the description of the RestartStrategy when I first read it and assumed that the configuration provided would enable restarting of the crashed application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change restart strategy to something like

```
RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 10, 1},
```

because 0, 1 means that app can't be restarted at all.